# Why No Set-Cookie Header from Yahoo finance (VC++)

Tags: visual-c++, cookies, yahoo-finance, setcookie

I try to get a cookie and crumb from Yahoo finance and use cookie/crumb to download Yahoo historical stock quote. But every time I try, I cannot get the
cookie because there is no Set-Cookie in response header.

Here is my Code:

```
CInternetSession MySession ("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1)   Chrome/49.0.2623.112", 1, PRE_CONFIG_INTERNET_ACCESS, NULL, NULL, 0);

DWORD dwHttpRequestFlags = INTERNET_FLAG_EXISTING_CONNECT 
                       | INTERNET_FLAG_NO_AUTO_REDIRECT 
                       | INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE 
                       | INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID 
                       | INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_DATE_INVALID;

CString szHeaders = _T("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) Chrome/49.0.2623.112"); 

INTERNET_PORT nPort = INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT;
CHttpConnection* pServer = NULL;
CHttpFile* pFile = NULL;
TCHAR sz [1025];

CString strServerName = "finance.yahoo.com";        
pServer = MySession.GetHttpConnection(strServerName, nPort);

try
{
    pFile = pServer->OpenRequest(CHttpConnection::HTTP_VERB_GET, "/quote/MSFT?p=MSFT", NULL, 1, NULL, "HTTP/1.1", dwHttpRequestFlags);
    pFile->SendRequest(szHeaders, NULL, 0);
    while (pFile->ReadString(sz, 1024))
    {
        //......
        //........
    }
    CString rawHead;
    pFile->QueryInfo(HTTP_QUERY_RAW_HEADERS_CRLF, rawHead, NULL);

}
```

I didn't see any Set-Cookie at all in Raw Header. What's wrong with my code?
How to get cookie from Yahoo finance with MFC? Thanks.

Comment: Try `INTERNET_FLAG_NO_COOKIES` flag. If I recall correctly, without this flag WinInet handles cookies automatically and doesn't pass them along to the application. Having said that - do you really need to see the cookie? WinInet does handle cookies automatically - in what way is that handling insufficient for your needs?

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I added INTERNET_FLAG_NO_COOKIES to dwHttpRequestFlags. Now I can get the cookie. Yes, I really need to see the cookie because I need to get the cookie and crumb to download historical stock quote from Yahoo.